# Refresh a div with ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So i have a comments box with a form (textbox and submit). This gets validated and then sent to the php page via ajax.

If all okay, the response is set and the page continues.

I want however the div to refresh itself so that you can see the new comment.

I dont want anything complicated like appending etc just simply to reload the div (data is pulled from database).

I have used this in the past but it doesnt work:

```
 $('#divid').load('page.php #divid'),
```

any idea how i can convert this:

```
        if (check == true) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process/addcomment.php",
        data: $targetForm.serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){

    if (response.databaseSuccess)
       $comment.after('<div class="error">Comment Added</div>');
    else
       $ckEditor.after('<div class="error">Something went wrong!</div>');

}
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

});

To refresh the div once the success gets responded?

if i try to add another $return to my php e.g

```
} catch (Exception $e) {
$return['databaseException'] = $e->getMessage();
}

$return['databaseSuccess'] = $dbSuccess;
$return['responseHtml'] = 'Post Updated';

echo json_encode($return);
```

the javascript doesnt work and i just get the php page load with the returns printed..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you do

```
$("#divid").html( "Comment Added" )
```

it will set the html within that div.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are meaning to do this

```
$('#divid').load('page.php');
```

checkout the jQuery[.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) documentation

Answer (score 0):

First you need some PHP code on the sever side that generates the HTML for the div. Then use this JavaScript

```
if (check == true) {
  $.ajax({
    type: ...,
    url: ...,
    data: ...,
    dataType: "html"
  })
    .done(function(responseHtml) {
      $("#yourDiv").html(responseHtml);
    });
}
```

Comment: if i try to update my php to this ending:

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $return['databaseException'] = $e->getMessage();
 }
 
 $return['databaseSuccess'] = $dbSuccess;
 $return['responseHtml'] = 'Post Updated';
     
 echo json_encode($return);
 
the javascript doesnt work and i just get the php page with return statements printed...

Comment: From your question I thought you wanted to 1) send the form data 2) refresh the div. To do this you need to return the HTML content for the div as the response to your ajax request. Note that if you return your data encoded as JSON rather then HTML, you have to use dataType: "html" and responseHtml in the example will be a JSON object.

Comment: A different solution would be starting another ajax request, for example .done(function(response) { if (response.success) /* Start here another ajax call to request HTML content */ });

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are processing the comment on the server after it has been submitted (validation/sanitation/etc.).  Therefor I would return the processed comment as part of the response and then insert it into the HTML:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process/addcomment.php",
    data: $targetForm.serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
        if (response.databaseSuccess) {
            // if you have a designated empty div already, you can use .html()
            $("#divid").html('<div class="success">'+response.commentText+'</div>');
            // if you want to append it to an already existing list of comments, you can use .append()
            $("#divid").append('<div class="success">'+response.commentText+'</div>');
        }
        else {
            $ckEditor.after('<div class="error">Something went wrong!</div>');
        }
    }
});
```

Of course, this will require you to add `response.commentText` to your returned JSON object.

Comment: for adding the reponse.comment text to my returned JSON object am i right in thinking i should add e.g: "$return['commentText'] = 'test comment';"

Comment: correct... however, I just noticed the PHP code on the bottom, so you could repurpose the `responseHtml` property (unless you need that for something else).

Comment: I use the example i gave in comment above, but to no avail. No change to the div and also even when e.g $(.commentsbox).html(commentText); it doesnt do anything but the comment is added...

Comment: Well... hard to tell what's going on... but here are a few questions: 1) Is there an element with a class of "commentsbox"?  Maybe it's an id instead of a class?  2) Did you assign `commentText` to `response.commentText`?  Because without the `response` part, it won't work.  3) Did you check if `response.commentText` i actually defined in the JSON?